# I don't get my bundle's data in onNewIntent method of MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-push-notification

I get a push notification in my FireBaseService and I want to send it's data to MainActivity, below is my code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("PUSH_NOTIFICATION");
    intent.setClassName(this, MainActivity.class.getName());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("data", data);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("notification bundle", bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

`onNewIntent()` gets called but when I parse it, it gives me null data. Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: My MainActivity launch mode is singleTop (to get same instance of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I read somewhere on Stackoverflow that Bundles have problem with Parcelable Objects, and it's better to convert them to Byte arrays and then bind them to Bundles, I didn't test it, but I bind JSON string itself and send it with Bundle and then parse it in onNewIntent() method, instead of parse it and send parcelable object, and it worked

Comment: Can you explain this a little further with an example?

Comment: It's really simple, just add your string which you got from firebase, add it to a Bundle, then send this bundle via Intent.
Just search for "pass an string via bundle to another activity", you will find so many sample.
Only wanna remind that you should make your target activity             android:launchMode="singleTask"
in manifest (to avoid lunch it again).
@ChristopherSmit

Comment: Thank you! this really help me solve my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented Firebase notifications in my app and I faced the same issue. The problem was when notification sent through Firebase console and app was in background the `onMessageReceived` method doesn't get called and `onNewIntent()` method returns null.

Try sending a push notification with the same payload through PostMan(RestApi Client). You will then be able to receive and fetch data in `onMessageRecieved` method of your receiver.

Comment: thanks Aditi, but I receive data through onMessageReceived  and no problem(whether app is background or foreground) , if you have problem with it I can help you  later, but this is not my problem

Comment: Are you sending data through firebase Console? And if your onMessageReceieved is called , you can further define the flow of the app through this method. There is no need for onNewIntent